# How to fetch records based on the max date in mongo document array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Below is the document which has an array name `datum` and I want to filter the records based on group by year and filter by the types and max date.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5fce46ca6ac9808276dfeb8c"),
    "year" : 2018,
    "datum" : [ 
        {
            "Type" : "1",
            "Amount" : NumberDecimal("100"),
            "Date" : ISODate("2018-05-30T00:46:12.784Z")
        }, 
        {
            "Type" : "1",
            "Amount" : NumberDecimal("300"),
            "Date" : ISODate("2023-05-30T00:46:12.784Z")
        }, 
        {
            "Type" : "2",
            "Amount" : NumberDecimal("340"),
            "Date" : ISODate("2025-05-30T00:46:12.784Z")
        }, 
        {
            "Type" : "3",
            "Amount" : NumberDecimal("300"),
            "Date" : ISODate("2021-05-30T00:46:12.784Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

The aggregate Query I tried.

```
[{$group: {
  _id :"$year",
  RecentValue : 
  {
     $sum: {
        $reduce: {
          input: '$datum',
          initialValue: {},
          'in': {
            $cond: 
         [
           {
             $and:
               [ 
                 {$or:[
        { $eq:  [ "$$this.Type", '2' ] }, 
        {$eq:  [ "$$this.Type", '3' ] }
        ]}, 
        { $gt:  [ "$$this.Date", "$$value.Date" ] },

                       ] 
           }
             , 
                "$$this.Amount",      
                 0     
            ]
          }
        }
      }
  }
}}]
```

---

the expected output would be which having the max date "2025-05-30T00:46:12.784Z"

```
{
_id   :2018,
RecentValue : 340 
}
```

Please let me know what mistake I did in the aggregate query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get max date before `$group` stage,

- `$addFields` to get document that having max date from, replaced `$or` with `$in` condition and corrected return value
- `$group` by `year` and sum `Amount`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      datum: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$datum",
          initialValue: {},
          "in": {
            $cond: [
              {
                $and: [
                  { $in: ["$$this.Type", ["2", "3"]] },
                  { $gt: ["$$this.Date", "$$value.Date"] }
                ]
              },
              "$$this",
              "$$value"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$year",
      RecentValue: { $sum: "$datum.Amount" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MhZrh7mn6pM)

Comment: how to exclude other fields except for the amount in the $addField Stage and also could you point out what mistake I did in my query.

Comment: You can not exclude other fields in this way because of the combination of your conditions and $reduce, it was excluded from $group stage,  your mistake is in `{ $gt: ["$$this.Date", "$$value.Date"] }` => `$$this.value` this is undefined because you can see `$cond`'s then and else part you returned Amount or 0, so `$$value` would be Amount or 0. so what i did in then and else part, i returned full object $$this or $$value

Comment: Will the add fields stage cause any performance-related issue and it will run again at least 1 million records.

Comment: I think no, addFields just filter your array and just getting required object only, to process in next $group stage. I am not sure for it will run over 1 million documents, it depends on schema design and indexing and collection scan in first stage, number of elements in array, and your server space and clustering plan, etc. for query optimization you can refer [aggregation-pipeline-optimization/](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/)